# Error when using hilt in multiple module project

Tags: android, kotlin, clean-architecture, dagger-hilt

In my project I have three modules :
1.app
2.data
3.domain

I am using hilt for dependency injection. But I keep getting the following error:

```
E:\Projects\AndroidStudioProjects\Fintock\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\com\example\fintock\Hilt_HiltApplication.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
      return DaggerHiltApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC.builder()
             ^
  symbol: variable DaggerHiltApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC
```

This is code for hilt modules :

**NetworkModule.kt** *(in data module)*

```
package com.example.data.di

import com.example.data.NetworkConstants
import com.example.data.api.AlphaVintageApi
import com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineCallAdapterFactory
import com.squareup.moshi.Moshi
import com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.reflect.KotlinJsonAdapterFactory
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import dagger.hilt.InstallIn
import dagger.hilt.components.SingletonComponent
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiConverterFactory
import javax.inject.Qualifier

@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
annotation class AlphaVintageRetrofit

@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
annotation class NewsApiRetrofit

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object NetworkModule {
    @Provides
    fun provideInterceptor(): HttpLoggingInterceptor {
        return HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideOkHttpClient(httpLoggingInterceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
            .build()
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideMoshiConverter(): MoshiConverterFactory {
        return MoshiConverterFactory.create(
            Moshi.Builder()
                .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
                .build()
        )
    }

    @AlphaVintageRetrofit
    @Provides
    fun provideAlphaVintageRetrofitModule(
        moshiConverterFactory: MoshiConverterFactory,
        okHttpClient: OkHttpClient
    ): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(NetworkConstants.ALPHA_VINTAGE_BASE_URL)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
            .addConverterFactory(moshiConverterFactory)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
    }

    @NewsApiRetrofit
    @Provides
    fun provideNewsApiRetrofitModule(
        moshiConverterFactory: MoshiConverterFactory,
        okHttpClient: OkHttpClient
    ): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(NetworkConstants.NEWS_API_BASE_URL)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
            .addConverterFactory(moshiConverterFactory)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideAlphaVintageServiceApi(@AlphaVintageRetrofit retrofit: Retrofit): AlphaVintageApi {
        return retrofit.create(AlphaVintageApi::class.java)
    }
}
```

**UsecaseModules.kt** *(in domain module)*

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object UsecaseModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideGetStockInformationUseCase(stockInDetailRepository: StockInDetailRepository) : GetStockInformationUseCase {
         return GetStockInformationUseCase(stockInDetailRepository)
    }
}
```

**HiltApplication.kt**

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class HiltApplication : Application()
```

The problem occurred when I tried to use clean architecture in my app. Before, when I had only one module(instead of three like I do now), there was no error.

I have been struck by this error for days, so any kind of help will be greatly appreciated. !!

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Please add more specific related error logs and also your MainApplication class

Comment: Hi @0xAliHn, thanks for responding. I added HiltApplication class, however, this is the only error shown when the build fails. There is nothing else.

Comment: it seems you have not added HiltApplication in manifest application tag.

Comment: In ```data``` module, you can provide ```StockInDetailRepository```

Comment: Hi @MohammadTauqir, i have added hilt application in manifest application tag

Comment: Hi @PhongBM, thank you!!. Solved the error .